# Is a continuous function f(x) independent of the input x_j if the gradient of f(x) w.r.t. x_j is always zero?

Tags: calculus

f(x) is a continuous function.
x is a J dimensional vector with each $x_j \in R$.

Is $f(x_{-j}) = f(x)$ thus f(x) is independent of $x_j$ if $\frac{d f(x_j)}{ d x_j}=0$.

Thus is a gradient that is always zero w.r.t to a certain input, enough for a continuous function to prove that its output value is independent of the specific input?

If this is true, how would I prove this mathematically?

Comment: let $\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{y} + \alpha\mathbf{e}_i$, that is, $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ differ only along the $i$ direction ($\mathbf{e}_i$ is the ``unit vector" in the ith direction), and assume $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x})}{\partial x_i}=0$. Then by the fundamental thm of calculus, $f(\mathbf{x})-f(\mathbf{y}) = \int_{t \in [0,\alpha]} \frac{\partial f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{e}_i)}{\partial x_i}$, and since the partial derivative is zero, the whole integral vanishes, leaving us with $f(\mathbf{x})=f(\mathbf{y})$, as desired.